# How do I maintain consistent positioning for desktop portion of my website as screen size changes?

Tags: html, css, position

https://github.com/FindleyDrummond2005/Unit13-L2-Website
Im having a big problem in how to change the size and positioning of the desktop part of the site so it stays in similar positions when the screen size changes, im really stuck and anything would help, thank you!

I tried using a wrapper for everything, I tried using percents, vw and vh, and nothing has seemed to work

Comment: please provide code minimal that denonstrates the problem, and include it in your question, rather than linking to it

Comment: You can use online editors like codepen, or jsFiddle, or use stackoverlow snippets